# Decoding an input stream

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a page that is accepting XML through a POST method. Here's a small bit of the code:

```
if (Request.ContentType != "text/xml")
        throw new HttpException(500, "Unexpected Content Type");

StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
string x = stream.ReadToEnd();  // added to view content of input stream

XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

I was getting an error, so I converted the stream to a string, just to see if everything was being sent correctly. When I looked at the content, it looked like this:

> %3c%3fxml+version%3d%271.0%27+encoding%3d%27UTF-8%27%3f%3e%0d%0a

So I guess I need to decode the stream. The only problem is that I don't know how I can use HtmlDecode on the stream, and still keep it as a StreamReader object.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It looks like the XML has been encoded an extra time, rather than just containing the XML. What's posting the data, and what *should* it be doing?

Comment: Looks like it's not html encoding, but url encoded string. Main question - why? Do you control side which posts an xml?

Comment: @invisible - no, I don't control the side that posts the xml

Comment: Could it be application/form-url-encoded ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apparently the client is sending the content as URL-encoded XML. So you need to decode the content like this:

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
string x = stream.ReadToEnd();
string xml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x);

XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.LoadXml(xml);
```

Anyway, the problem is probably on the client side... why is it encoding the XML this way?

Comment: @Jcorretjer what I suggested in my answer is only useful in the OP's use case. Using this on an arbitrary file upload makes no sense.

Comment: be careful with StreamReader it inherited from TextReader that  inherited from  IDisposable and must to be Dispose or use in Using statement